# Replace all URL occurrences of string by another in Node js

Tags: javascript, node.js, string

I am trying to replace all occurrences of `http://xyz.yzx.com/abc/def/` by `/qwe/` in `String` in Node js. I am very new to Node js. So, I think I am doing some mistake in syntax. Following is the code with which I am trying.

```
var newString = originalString.replace("http:\/\/xyz\.yzx\.com\/abc\/def\//g", "/qwe/");
```

But this is not doing any replace. Can someone suggest what I am doing wrong? I have tried lot of tweaks but somehow I am not able to achieve the replace all occurrences.

Any suggestions you can give would be really appreciated.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to replace all occurrences of a string in JavaScript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1144783/how-to-replace-all-occurrences-of-a-string-in-javascript)

Comment: Actually I tried using the same way but somehow I am doing some mistake which I am not able to found out. If you can help me found the mistake in my code, that would be great.

Comment: If you wanna use regex (`//g`) you dont need the string literal `""` ...

Comment: Hmmm, I did not test the code in Node, but a tool tells me, your regex is good enough: https://regex101.com/r/we8LHA/1  Could  you provide a repro case? (A string on which the replacement fails)

Comment: @igor theres no regex in the users code ;)

Comment: @Jonasw If I don't use the "", then it is showing compile time error at :(colon) part.

Comment: @igor a string is a string :/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If a string is passed as replaces first argument it will only replace the first occurence ( which is badly implemented in my opinion). So we either use a small workaround:

```
var newString = originalString
   .split("http:\/\/xyz\.yzx\.com\/abc\/def")
   .join("/qwe/");
```

Or we need to remove the string literal and escape every `/` with a `\/` ... :/

Comment: Now, I see. The regex _literal_ was not used.

Answer (score 1):

This works fine, have a look:

```
originalString.replace(/\http:\/\/xyz\.yzx\.com\/abc\/def\//g, '/qwe/')
```